# What is the ideal way to store the consumer offset using spring boot kafka consumer client?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have spring kafka consumer application. The application acts as pass through which polls the messages from kafka broker and send to IBM MQ. What would be a best/simplistic approach to store the offset in case of failure?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to use the default mechanism of storing the offsets in kafka itself.

If you add a `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler`, the container will keep redelivering records that are failed in the listener, up to 10 times by default but it can be configured for infinite retries.

If you add stateful retry, the listener adapter can add a delay between each delivery attempt.

See [Stateful Retry](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#stateful-retry).

`ackOnError` should be set to `false`.